# How run php script (cron or not cron) on VPS every second?

Tags: cron, vps

*Good day.*

*Standart options cron can run script every minute.*

```
* * * * *  wget -q -O - https://test.com/index.php?Cmd=Start --no-check-certificate > /dev/null 2>&1 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

*But what we are should do to run php script every second(and without sleep in php code) ?*

*I would appreciate any help!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*With cron it will be next:*

```
* * * * * /path/to/script
* * * * * sleep 1; /path/to/script
* * * * * sleep 2; /path/to/script
* * * * * sleep 3; /path/to/script
....
....
* * * * * sleep 59; /path/to/script
```